# how do i mock rest template exchange method

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am trying to mock rest template exchange method.

```java
String responseBody = "responseBody";
String url = "http://example.com";
HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.GET;
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = null;
Class<String> responseType = String.class;
Object[] uriVariables = {};
    
Map<String, String> headers = Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");
when(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, responseType,uriVariables))
    .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK));
```

but getting this error,

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>, Object...) in the type RestTemplate 
    is not applicable for the arguments (String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<String>, Class<String>, Object[])   line 45 Java Problem
```

i am not able to understand which argument is causing this error.
can anyone please help

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my machine. My guess is you import one of the classes (like HttpEntity, HttpMethod) from some other library. Show us your imports.

Comment: right, issue was due to wrong import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the most likely cause is wrong import.

The error message makes it difficult to find by  not printing fully qualified class names.